# How to get the number of coins in Java?

Tags: java

I have my code where user enters an amount of money and the output displays the number of Twenties, tens, fives, ones, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies, **but** I would like the user to enter an amount of coins (for example 36) and get the number of **ONLY COINS** that makes for the 36 cents. Meaning that I should get 1 Quarter, 1 dime, and 1 pennie. Please someone help me on this. Thanks a lot!

**NOTE:

DecimalFormat class is not neccessary**

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Compu
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    System.out.println("Please Enter an amount of Money:");       
    double change = input.nextDouble();


    int dollars = (int)change;
    int twenties = dollars / 20;
    int dollars1 = dollars % 20;
    int tens = dollars1 / 10;
    int dollars2 = dollars % 10;
    int fives = dollars2 / 5;
    int dollars3 = dollars % 5;
    int ones = dollars3;

    String moneyString = decimalFormat.format(change);
    String changeString = Double.toString(change); 
    String[] parts = moneyString.split("\\.");
    String part2 = parts[1]; 
    double cents5 = Double.parseDouble(part2);

    int cents = (int)cents5;
    int quarters = cents / 25;
    int cents1 = cents % 25;
    int dimes = cents1 / 10;
    int cents2 = cents % 10;
    int nickels = cents2 / 5;
    int cents3 = cents % 5;
    int pennies = cents3;

    System.out.println("Input entered by user: " + "$" + moneyString);


    System.out.println(twenties + " Twenties");
    System.out.println(tens + " Tens");
    System.out.println(fives + " Fives");
    System.out.println(ones + " Ones");
    System.out.println(quarters + " Quarters");
    System.out.println(dimes + " Dimes");
    System.out.println(nickels + " Nickels");
    System.out.println(pennies + " Pennies");

  }
}
```

Comment: How is it different than entering `0.36` into your program?

Comment: @PM77-1 that I dont want to enter 0.36. I just want to enter 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus operator is your friend:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter amount in cents");
    double cents = input.nextInt();

    int numQuarters = cents / 25;
    int numDimes    = (cents % 25) / 10;
    int numNickels  = ((cents % 25) % 10) / 5;
    int numPennies  = ((cents % 25) % 10) % 5;

    System.out.println(quarters + " Quarters");
    System.out.println(dimes    + " Dimes");
    System.out.println(nickels  + " Nickels");
    System.out.println(pennies  + " Pennies");
}
```

Comment: what if I also want the number of nickles?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, completely remove the part of the program that deals with dollars, and feed the user input directly to 'cents'.

Also, this part:

```
int cents = (int)cents5;
int quarters = cents / 25;
int cents1 = cents % 25;
int dimes = cents1 / 10;
int cents2 = cents % 10;
int nickels = cents2 / 5;
int cents3 = cents % 5;
int pennies = cents3;
```

Will be inaccurate (in a few cases. Not all), as you aren't changing the value of 'cents'. Therefore, if you input '36', it will return 1 quarter (25), 1 dime (35), 1 nickel (40), and 1 penny (41).

To avoid this, use the following code:

```
int cents = (int)cents5;
int quarters = cents / 25;
int cents1 = cents % 25;
int dimes = cents1 / 10;
int cents2 = cents1 % 10;
int nickels = cents2 / 5;
int cents3 = cents2 % 5;
int pennies = cents3;
```